# Mysql group_concat error

Tags: mysql

I have a table like

```
Id    Name    Location
1     A       New York
2     A       Melbourne
3     B       Mumbai
4     B       Paris
```

I need result in the following format :

```
Name    Location
A       New York , Melbourne
B       Mumbai , Paris
```

I tried `select names , group_concat(location separator ',') from table;`
but didn't get the expected output.

Answer (score 2):

You need also `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT Name, GROUP_CONCAT(Location) AS Location
FROM your_table
GROUP BY Name
```

Also `SEPARATOR` is comma by default.